# Spring Data for Couchbase: use of AND ANY ... SATISFIES

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I have a SpringBoot 2 app that uses using Couchbase as a database, Spring-Boot and Spring-Data and Lombok fot the getters and equals method
I have created this Repository

```
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "bendicionesDoc")
public interface BenRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<BendicionesDoc, String> {

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} AND ANY uuid IN data.identifier.id SATISFIES uuid = $1 END")
    List<BendicionesDoc<Item>> findById(String id);


}
```

and here all the objects created with Lombok library

```
public class BendicionesDoc<T>implements Serializable {


        @Field
        private T data;

    }
```

and

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class Item {

    private List<Identifier> identifier;


}
```

and

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Identifier {

    private String id;
    private MasterServant idContext;
    private MasterServant idScope;

}
```

and

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class MasterServant {

    private String context;
    @JsonValue
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String value;

    private Name valueDescription;

    @JsonCreator
    public MasterServant(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

But when I run the repository query I got always 0 results, even there are docs. in the DB:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your `reference type` in `CouchbaseRepository<T, K>` then simply add the reference type `Item` as `CouchbaseRepository<BendicionesDoc<Item>, String>` and just use [Repository query keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) for `findById(String id)`.

```
public interface BenRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<BendicionesDoc<Item>, String> { 

    List<BendicionesDoc<Item>> findById(String id);

}
```